# How to pass .class to ObjectMapper while trying to generify a method using it?

Tags: java, json, spring, generics, generic-programming

I have an app written using Spring, and I have a problem with ObjectMapper. The problem is within a method which I am trying to generify.

I looks like this:

```
public T getResponse(U senderJsonModel, T response) {
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(createSendRequest(senderJsonModel), headers);
    String answer = restTemplate.postForObject(apiAddress, entity, String.class);
    try {
        response = mapper.readValue(answer, response.getClass());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error mapping JSON values to Object", e);
    }
    return response;
}
```

I am getting a null pointer exception when it hits the line

```
response = mapper.readValue(answer, response.getClass());
```

I have tried with `TypeReference<T>(){}` but I got:

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.app.infrastructure.sender.emailsender.response.EmailHttpResponse

Under U i am passing an instance of EmailJsonModel class, and under T i am passing an instance of EmailHttpResponse class.

I cannot find a way how to pass the .class to this method, is there even a way to do this?

Comment: Is your mapper variable initialised and not null? What have you tried with TypeReference<T>(){}?

Comment: pass a `Class<T> clazz` instead of `T`. and use it like `T result = mapper.readValue(answer, clazz);` and then `return result;`

Comment: @Jim_Ktr I am pretty sure `TypeReference<T>(){}` will not work as `T` will be `Object` at runtime.